# Generate Random Value Located Within Cell Within Range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking for a formula script that will run when a cell is clicked (or selected and then run the script). The script itself I'm wanting to look at a range of cells (such as I2:I35) and pick a value from one of them randomly.

I'm not new to code, especially JS, but I am new to working with Google's scripting language, so I'm not entirely sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

After doing a bit of research I found that it would seem to be impossible to do this when a cell is simply clicked. To combat this I decided to pass in a second argument to be the cell that triggers the [onEdit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedite) to change the result.

*You will need to add a trigger to this custom function as well for it to work properly.*

**To use this, simply type `=RANDOMITEM(cell_to_edit, beginning_cell:ending_cell)` in the function text area or the cell itself.**

**Example: `=RANDOMITEM(A1, B1:B10)` would use A1 as the trigger cell so that when it's edited it will select a random item from cell B1-B10**

```
/**
 * Picks a random value from a range of cells.
 *
 * @param {number} editCell The cell which will be used as the trigger.
 * @param {number} itemRange The cells to be picked from.
 * @return The random value from the range of cells.
 * @customfunction
 */
function RANDOMITEM(editCell,itemRange) {
  var itemArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < itemRange.length; i++) {
    itemArray.push(itemRange[i]);
  };
  var result = itemArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*itemArray.length)];

  return result;
}
```